# Measuring an AC-voltage at the ouput of a full bridge rectifier

Tags: voltage, ac, measurement, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I've a full bridge rectifier and I put the following function into it:

$$5\sin(100\pi t)\tag1$$

So, at the output I get:

$$\left|(5-2V_d)\sin(100\pi t)\right|\tag2$$

Where \$V_d\$ is the voltage over one diode.

Now, why do I measure (with a Fluke multimeter) a DC-voltage of \$1.4\$ volts and an AC-voltage of \$0.5\$ volts. Why do I measure an AC-voltage, is it not completely DC?

Comment: The AC will be a measure of the ripple. What do you mean by a "fluxe multimeter". Do you mean "Fluke"? (Note the capital 'F'.)

Comment: @Transistor Yes sorry it is Fluke. So it will measure the RMS ripple?

Comment: Is it a 'true RMS' meter? Also your equation (2) is not correct.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany What should the right equation be?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I do not understand what you mean?!

Comment: If your Vd was 3V (pretty unlikely but hey), then your output voltage would be 0V. In your equation, the output voltage would be |-1*sin(100*pi*t)|, which is not 0V.

Comment: @BeB00 Yes I understand.

Comment: I've put it as an answer so I can use the equation formatting (and corrected it).

Answer (score 1):

Equation (2) should be:

$$v(t) = \begin{cases}|(5\sin(100πt)|-2V_D ,& |5\sin(100πt)| > 2V_D \\0 ,& \  |5\sin(100πt)| <= 2V_D\end{cases}$$

The exact reading of a voltage that is not a pure sine wave (zero average voltage) on the AC range of a multimeter depends on whether the multimeter is AC or DC coupled and whether it is true-RMS or average-reading, corrected to RMS.

Example (resistive load of 1K):

[image]

Comment: Where does that formula comes from?

Comment: @Looper Comes from my brain. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: That is not what I mean, haha :). I mean why does the hole function get's lowered by \$2Vd\$ and not only the amplitude of the sine function?

Comment: The input voltage to the bridge has to exceed 2 diode drops or the output stays at zero. So there are flat sections with voltage zero between the rectified half sine waves (assuming a resistive load to deal with diode leakage and capacitance).