# What does a multimeter read when you measure unstable DC-voltage

Tags: dc, measurement, multimeter

When I have a Fluke True-RMS multimeter. Does the meter measure DC-RMS voltage or the average voltage?

Comment: What is the frequency of the instability? Does your meter have a range that shows AC voltage with a DC offset?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well for example the output of a full bridge rectifier?

Comment: I have no reason to suppose that the meter would use its RMS-measurement circuitry when it's set to read DC. I would expect it to show a wildly varying voltage depending on when it took a sample. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton When I tried \$5\$ volts amplitude and \$50\$ Hz as frequency of the input sine-wave I got \$1.4\$ volts at the output (that is what the Fluke read)

Comment: What circuit are you referring to? Is it a half wave rectifier?

Comment: @Looper: Have you forgotten to mention that there's [a bridge rectifier in there too](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370276/measuring-an-ac-voltage-at-the-ouput-of-a-full-bridge-rectifier)? Why doesn't your question include the model of the Fluke meter with a hyperlink to the datasheet?